# How to make updated progress bar in Android inside a Notification?

Tags: android, notifications, progress-bar

I am having a question on Notification + ProgressBar in Android. I want to develop a functionality like the Installation of apk from Google Play. What i want is when anyone install any app from the market the user will be able to see the progress of that installation in Notification area. I want to develop same kind of thing in my app. How can i show the updated progress of some activity in notification area?

If anyone has any idea please kindly help me or provide me some resources for tutorials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Provide a custom view to your notification : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView